How do I change the width and height of an Angular Material dialog for mobile view only?
I'm developing an Angular application and using Angular Material for the UI. I want to adjust the width and height of a dialog, but only for mobile view. I don't know how to resize only the mobile view while leaving the desktop view unchanged. I would like to know how best to implement this scenario. Thanks in advance for your help! Changing the width or height property in the CSS also had no effect on the width or height of the dialog.
Here is my code: It only works, if my css is in global_styles.css
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-uum6dr?file=src%2Fglobal_styles.css

I don't really understand your problem.. You can just set the width and height of the dialog container inside a media query. It works for me when playing around in the docs. Note that when changing the container height, you will also need to adjust the content max-height for a good scrolling behavior.

I've got it done now. See Stackblitz link in the question. But it only works if I define the CSS in global_styles.css. Is it also possible to define the CSS outside of global_styles.css?

For that purpose you can use panelClass property of MatDialogConfig in combination with @media only in CSS
Example:
//component.ts
import { MatDialog } from "@angular/material/dialog";

constructor(private dialog: MatDialog) {}

public openDialog() {
  return this.dialog.open(DialogComponent, { panelClass: "mobile-width" });
}

// in css
@media only screen and (max-width: 760px) {
    .mobile-width {
        width: 200px;
    }
}


I've got it done now. See Stackblitz link in the question. But it only works if I define the CSS in global_styles.css. Is it also possible to define the CSS outside of global_styles.css?
